# Como converter um número int para string em python?

Tags: python, string, inteiros

Preciso fazer um exercício no qual eu inputo uma variável inteira de 3 dígitos e o python tem que mostrar ele invertido, mas ate aonde eu sei uma variável inteira n pode fazer isso, mas uma string sim. O que eu posso fazer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar:

```
str(10);
```

E de string para int você pode usar:

```
int('10');
```

Answer (score 5):

Para reverter a string que retorna do `input()`, cujo já retorna uma string e não um inteiro, podes fazer assim:

```
num = input("introduza um num") # '123'
revertido = num[::-1]
print(revertido) # '321'
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/7nONyV)

Mas para transformar um inteiro em string e reverter seria:

```
str(123)[::-1] # '321'
```

Como é mencionado em outras respostas.

E para teres essa reversão outra vez em inteiro:

```
int(str(123)[::-1]) # 321
```

Answer (score 4):

Quando você diz

> eu inputo uma variável inteira de 3 dígitos

Interpretado como

> eu leio da entrada padrão um inteiro

Se você está usando Python 3, você lê da entrada padrão com a função `input`, sendo o retorno sempre uma string. Assim, inverter o número seria inverter a string. Caso esteja usando Python 2, a função `input` retornará um número mesmo, mas você poderia usar o `raw_input`, que retorna uma string.

Documentação:

- Python3 `input`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input
- Python2 `input`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input
- Python2 `raw_input`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

---

Interpretando como uma função na qual será enviado um número, você pode converter para string conforme a [resposta do David Melo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192228/64969).

---

Interpretando como fazer essa inversão usando apenas operações matemáticas, você pode recorrer ao módulo e à divisão inteira.

Por exemplo, em Python 3:

```
a = 123 # número a inverter
b = 0 # número invertido

for i in range(3):
    # pegue o último dígito de 'a' e coloque após os valores atuais de 'b'
    b = b*10 + (a % 10)
    # remova o último dígito de 'a'
    a = a//10
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão basta:

1. Capturar o valor numérico como string;
2. Reverter esta string;
3. Exibir o valor revertido.

Com esta lógica podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
print(input('Digite um número com 3 dígitos: ')[::-1])
```

Quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite um número com 3 dígitos:` . Neste momento devemos digitar um número inteiro com 3 dígitos e pressionar `enter`.

A partir deste momento o `input()` capturará o valor digitado, reverterá a ordem dos dígitos e, em seguida, exibirá o valor revertido.

Answer (score 0):

Há uma forma matemática de inverter um número, que funciona para qualquer quantidade de dígitos:

```
import math

def inverte(n):
    digitos = int(math.ceil(math.log10(n)))
    return sum(n / 10**p % 10 * 10**(digitos-p-1) for p in range(digitos))
```

Primeiro precisamos saber o número de dígitos de um número. O logaritmo de base 10 nos diz isso, quando arredondado para cima.

Depois, precisamos rodar o seguinte algoritmo, uma vez por posição *p* (um número de 3 dígitos vai ter posições 0, 1 e 2):

- Dividir o número por 10 elevado à potência *p* (isso vai "mover" o número que queremos na posição *p* para o fim do número);
- Obter o resto da divisão desse número por 10 (isso vai isolar o último número);
- Multiplicar este resto por 10 elevado à potência **digitos-p-1** (isso vai colocar o número na posição correta no número final)

Por fim, somamos os números resultantes de cada iteração, e teremos o número invertido.

Um exemplo de execução:

```
numero = 1234
digitos = 4
p0:
  1234 / (10 ** 0) = 1234 / 1 = 1234
  1234 % 10 = 4
  4 * (10 ** (4 - 0 - 1)) = 4 * (10 ** 3) = 4 * 1000 = 4000
p1:
  1234 / (10 ** 1) = 1234 / 10 = 123
  123 % 10 = 3
  3 * (10 ** (4 - 1 - 1)) = 3 * (10 ** 2) = 3 * 100 = 300
p2:
  1234 / (10 ** 2) = 1234 / 100 = 12
  12 % 10 = 2
  2 * (10 ** (4 - 2 - 1)) = 2 * (10 ** 1) = 2 * 10 = 20
p3:
  1234 / (10 ** 3) = 1234 / 1000 = 1
  1 % 10 = 1
  1 * (10 ** (4 - 3 - 1)) = 1 * (10 ** 0) = 1 * 1 = 1

soma = 4000 + 300 + 20 + 1 = 4321
```