# Inverter Número

Tags: python, funções, lógica

Qual lógica eu poderia empregar para fazer um programa onde eu insiro um número e depois seja invertido.

ex: 123 para 321

PS: tem que ser uma função.

Comment: E ainda mais duplicata de [Como converter um número int para string em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192225/5878)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953303/how-to-reverse-an-int-in-python   IDEONE  https://ideone.com/bF8dyh